# TimeMill creating too big MBtile file too large

Tags: dictionary, mapbox, tilemill

I have been learning MapBox form last some days and i find it quite good . I have been facing a particular problem. Suppose I need to create a layer for various states of a country. I have TileMIll with me so no problem while creating layer and modifying it. But I need it upto zoom level 20. So thats making size too big(100 GB+). I tried with png8 . So up to level zoom level 17 I was able to create MBTile file of size 99.6 MB(actually it was showing 1GB+). So please let me know is there any way to achieve zoom level as required without making .MBTile size too big? I guess L.tileLayer.wms can help me here

Answer (score 1):

As I asked this same question to MapBox team and they are really quick to reply. 
So following their advice  I tried to make different layers one upto zoom 17, then 17 to 18 and so on and use them as required and it worked . Maybe it can help somebody.